# bash - unable to echo array value

Tags: arrays, bash

I have four cameras and want to store output from any of it in empty array and get output code from any array member.

```
        # streams to check
        streams=("rtsp://Streaming/Channels/01" "rtsp://Streaming/Channels/201" "rtsp://Streaming/Channels/301" "rtsp://Streaming/Channels/401")
        # declare array for stream codes
        declare -a  outputcodes
           
        for stream in "${streams[@]}"; do
           streamoutput=$(timeout 20s ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_streams $stream)
           # get output code for each stream  
           streamresults=$(jq -r '.streams[0].index' <<< "$streamoutput")
          # add stream result to array          
          outputcodes+=$streamresults
           done
        exit 0
    # get first array member result   
    echo ${outputcodes[0]}
```

the problem is that `echo ${outputcodes[0]} echo ${outputcodes}` shows nothing

What's the problem ?

when i add `echo $streamresults` to for loop i'm getting correct results

```
0
0
0
0
```

setting `outputcodes+=($streamresults)` changes nothing

Bash version:4.2.46(2)-release

Tried to declare array in this way but same output:

```
declare -a outputcodes=()
```

Comment: Please add output of `declare -p outputcodes` to your question (no comment here).

Comment: declare: outputcodes: not found

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot, had `exit 0` before echoing array, once removed it all works.
Sorry for bothering